# R - Imply the x object in grep

Tags: r

I am regularly filtering character vectors by using grep in the index. For this, I usually repeat the name of the indexed object in the index.

```
paths <- c("Resources/ctrl1.txt", "Resources/ctrl2.txt", 
           "Resources/trt1.txt", "Resources/trt2.txt")

paths.ctrl <- paths[grep("ctrl", paths)]
```

I was wondering, if there was a way to imply the `x` (the object in which the pattern is sought), so I don't need to name it explicitly again. This would be especially handy when the object is not assigned yet, and the filtering happens already during the assignment.

Instead of:

```
dir <- "Resources/"
paths.ctrl <- paste0(dir, list.files(dir, recursive=T)[grep("ctrl", list.files(dir, recursive=T)))
```

I would like something like:

```
paths.ctrl <- paste0(dir, list.files(dir, recursive=T)[grep("ctrl", x)]
```

I know that I can use the pattern argument in case of `list.files`, but I'm hitting this issue in all kinds of contexts and was wondering if there was a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you will like is the `value = TRUE` option, as in

```
paths.ctrl <- paste0(dir, grep("ctrl", list.files(dir, recursive = TRUE), value = TRUE))
```

E.g.,

```
c("AA", "BB", "BA")[grep("B", c("AA", "BB", "BA"))]
# [1] "BB" "BA"

grep("B", c("AA", "BB", "BA"), value = TRUE) # no repetitions
# [1] "BB" "BA"
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! :)